# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �zq (U+EC) - web site

Tags: bibtex, input-encodings, tools

Im getting the following error message, due to my bibtex source

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �zq (U+EC)
```

I know it is because somewhere, some how some a special m!@$$êr character has sneaked behind my back, and found a nice hiding spot in my bibliography. I remember there is a site where i can copy-past text and any utf characters (hidden or not) show up, where then I can later remove these pests.

Can some kind soul point me to a relevant site, or a method in .txt that I can do this. This is driving me mad.

Peace and love,
G

Comment: U+00EC should normally be setup automatically. But you could try `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EC}{HERE-HERE-HERE}` in your preamble. Perhaps you can then see the location after the next compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any online regexp tester, such as the one at https://regex101.com/

[image: Screenshot]

Introduce as regexp the following expression:

```
([^\x00-\x7F])
```

and a `g` at the input box after the `/`

Then paste your text in the big text area below, and you'll get at the right, in the "Match information" panel all the non-ascii chars in your input (which are also higlighted in green in the text area).

If you get "`Your pattern does not match the subject string.`", your text ASCII only :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) and search for non ascii char with the regular expression `[^\x00-\x7F]`, you have to activate regular expressions in the left lower corner of the search window. 
EDIT: just find found out Notepad++ allready covers that:

[`Search | Find characters in range | Non-ASCII Characters (128-255)| 
you can then step through the document to each non-ascii character.`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23705696)

You can also convert the bib file with Notepad++ to the convert encoding.

Make sure the Inputenc `\usepackage[]{inputenc}` is set to the same encoding  and the output `\usepackage[]{fontenc}` also. Then confiugre Biblatex for the same Encoding `\usepackage[ backend=biber, bibencoding= ]{biblatex}`.